# Issue with white space when changing from landscape to portrait on mobile/tablet

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

A website I am working on for a personal project requires a large background image (full screen) below this just offscreen is my container div `<main>`, user scrolls down the screen and this container div overlays the large background image until the user reaches the page bottom `<footer>`.

This works perfectly on any screen size **but only in landscape view**, now I know this is due to the fact that the `<main>` div is set to appear just off-screen by having a body height css of 100%, however this causes issues when viewing in portrait view as this will then push the `<main>` div right down to the bottom of the screen leaving a huge white space below the background image which I do not want.

Do I have to run media queries to solve this?.. (I would sooner not as media queries are great but they don't really account for user resizing screen by dragging the edges around), or am I missing something in my css or finally can it be fixed via javascript?.

More info: Bootstrap v3.3.7, 
https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/

css:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/* div holding the background image */
.mainbg {
    background-image: url("../images/main_image.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="mainbg"></div>

    <main role="main">
       <!-- Intro Section -->
    <section id="intro" class="intro-section mobile-block">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <h1>Stack Overflow Question</h1>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "media queries are great but they don't really account for user resizing screen by dragging the edges around". First, media queries based on the window width ***do*** respond to the user resizing the window. Second, there are also media queries for the hardware screen size, which may be what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have posted enough code for me to give you a working example, but the general idea is that you could use media queries to modify the the css based on viewport width.

Maybe it could be as simple as something like

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {   /* adjust breakpoint as req'd */
   .mainbg {
     height:75%;   /* adjust as req'd, could be % or sometimes pixel value is easier to work with on narrow viewports  */
   }
}
```

or maybe you'll need to use more than one media request to target different viewports

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
       .mainbg {
         ....
       }
    }    

 @media (max-width: 480px) {
       .mainbg {
         ...
       }
    }
```

or occasionally slightly more complex media queries like

```
/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */ 
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .mainbg {
     ...
   }
        }
```

Remember that the usual CSS cascading rules apply so take care to get the order or your media queries correct and have these rules in the correct position in your stylesheet.

> Do i have to run media queries to solve this?.. (i would sooner not as
>   media queries are great but they dont really account for user resizing
>   screen by dragging the edges around), or am i missing something in my
>   css or finally can it be fixed via javascript?.

You could do it with javascript, as a general rule solving it with CSS will be easier. If you use media queries there's no problem user resizes screen, it will work.

Hope this helps!